# can we do spring generic mapping to views?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring. What i want is i will be having various jsp pages and i will map user request to those JSP pages.My question is "can we map user requests to jsp pages when request url and jsp names are same using spring controller mapping".I searched and not found anything.

like without writing controller

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Found it UrlFilenameViewController is the best option where we can use html pages also as view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I mis-read the question, but if you wanted to map a URL to a JSP directly (e.g. without having to define a controller & method) then that can be done pretty easily (as you would hope)

XML config:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/help-page" view-name="helpPage"/>
```

or if you are using Java Config (extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/help-page").setViewName("helpPage");
    }
```

Using either of the above, if you visit /help-page then it will render the /WEB-INF/jsp/helpPage.jsp

Comment: Very Very Thanks , This is what i wanted wanted.But with addViewController("some value not known").setViewName("some value not known");                                                                          ie. to be known dynamically

Comment: When no model is needed this is the perfect solution. +1

Comment: @FaizAli never tried dynamic mapping - but see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6944473/258813  - looks like he is just mapping /** to the UrlFilenameViewController - but as pointed out if you later want to add controllers you will need to add all those mappings as exclsuions

Answer (score 1):

By default Spring MVC registeres a `DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator` which will translate the request into a view name similar to your requirements.

Simply use `Map` as a return type and the translation commences.
Returning a `Map` will expose it as the model for the view.

You can also return `void` but you'll have to make sure no `HttpServletResponse` is declared as an argument.

```
@RequestMapping("/registration/form")
public ModelMap form(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("form", new FormObject());
    return model;
}
```

Will translate to view name: `"registration/form"`

Comment: please give me a link of sample ,or just paste a sample here

Comment: Use Map as a return type for what?

Comment: @blank Sorry for the confusion. Added some explanation.

Comment: I still don't get it. What are you meant to use map as a return type for?

Comment: @FaizAli Added an example

Comment: @blank With providing a model without a view Spring will rely on a `RequestToViewNameTranslator` to translate the request into a logical view name.

Comment: but what i want is "/registration/form" should be known dynamically like  @RequestMapping("somevale") and model redirect it to somevalue.jsp

Comment: got it means i need to put @RequestMapping(/*)

Comment: @blank Have a look at [this piece of documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). If you search for *"The following return types are supported for handler methods"* you will find a section that explains all the return types.