# Spring MVC separate request for controller and static resource or html/jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

What I want to achieve:

Http request for:

*.css, *.js, *.html, *.xhtml, *.jsp, *.png, *.jpg, *.gif

---> should call the resource or view files (html, jsp) **directly** and not be processed by DispatcherServlet and any Controller.

**Every other** http request should be processed by DispatcherServlet and some mapped Controller.

I want to build a CMS system that generates static html and jsp files dynamically, so there will be no controllers for these files. But the files should be accessible by name.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mvc:resources` to achieve the same.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/public-resources/" />
```

Refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195213/spring-3-mvc-resources-and-tag-mvcresources)

Comment: if i do that and create '/WEB-INF/public-resources/example.jsp'  will the jsp file be processed ?

Comment: no no..this is not for jsp but for resources like *.css, *.js, *.png, *.jpg, *.gif etc.

Comment: I also need direct jsp call without controller (dispatcher servlet) in between

Comment: for that you refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933464/spring-webmvc-mapping-the-jsp-without-controllers